# Foursquare Venue/search api gives error code 429 after 500 request for credit card verified account

Tags: foursquare

I am using credit card verified account to access venues/search api.
I am making userless request with my client_id and client_secret but after 500 request start getting error code 429 daily quota exceeded.
Earlier same account was working for thousands of request.Since yesterday i start getting the error.

Below is my api call and respective error.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=-7.67226,111.22648&intent=browse&radius=30&client_id=XXXX&client_secret=XXXXJ0B&v=20191306&m=foursquare&categoryId=4d4b7104d754a06370d81259,4d4b7105d754a06372d81259,4d4b7105d754a06373d81259,4d4b7105d754a06374d81259,4d4b7105d754a06376d81259,4d4b7105d754a06377d81259,4d4b7105d754a06375d81259,4e67e38e036454776db1fb3a,4d4b7105d754a06378d81259,4d4b7105d754a06379d81259

```
{"meta":{"code":429,"errorType":"quota_exceeded","errorDetail":"Quota exceeded","requestId":"5d01ba38018cbb002c1757d7"},"response":{}}
```

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I am experiencing the same thing with a credit card verified account.

Comment: @Dallan After the issue comes I tried to login my fq developer account and it was asking to change the password after changing the password simply restarted my application and it back to normal. (Changing the password was bit troublesome because I was not getting the password reset link then i connect with support - https://support.foursquare.com/hc/en-us and they send the reset link) Hope this help

Comment: Same issue again started so it seems it is from FQ API issue.

Comment: Have you figured out this issue status code 429 from foursquare api

Comment: I remove my credit card , Update the access token and again verify my credit card. Since then there is no 429 error. Recently they have changed quota limit for per user. 
        https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/places-api/rate-limits/